# Add a custom layout to Activity's layout dynamically

Tags: android

I have a few custom `LinearLayout`s which I want to add dynamically to an `Activity`'s main `RelativeLayout`.
This is one of my custom layouts:

```
public class MyLayout1 extends LinearLayout {...}
```

This is the `my_layout_1.xml` file for it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<***myPackageName***.MyLayout1 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
......
</***myPackageName***.MyLayout1>
```

I add the custom layout to the `RelativeLayout` using this code:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_layout_1, mainLayout, false); //mainLayout is the id of the main RelativeLayout
mainLayout.addView(view, params);
```

The code works fine.
But when I use `findViewById(...)` function in my custom `MyLayout1` class, it returns `null` for all views. How can I bind the `.xml` file and the Java class? I thought that adding the package+class name in `.xml` was enough, but I was wrong.
Also I tried to call

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout_1, null);
```

in `MyLayout1` class, but the `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>` error message is shown in the Log window.

Comment: Do you mean findViewById()   (no s)

Comment: How are you getting to the code in your class?  Is it in a constructor?  In a method called from somewhere else?

Comment: O, yes. Sorry. I will change it now.

Comment: You need to be sure that "this" references the view that was inflated from the XML and added to the relative layout.

Comment: At the time your view is constructed, the child views have not yet been added.   You'll have to defer trying to find them until later.

Comment: You might be able to find the views in onFinishedInflate or in the first call to onLayout (be sure to call the corresponding super.* methods.)

Comment: I spent too much time to find the correct answer... Thank you very much! My problem is solved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to call `findViewById()` to get access to the instances of Views that are declared inside of your layout.xml file then you need to do this in [`View#onfinishInflate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onFinishInflate%28%29). This is called once the view is finished inflating. In that function you can use `findViewById()` successfully. When the using `findViewById()` in the constructor when a view is being inflated the child views will not have been instantiated and added yet. This is why it is returning null.